# Netsuite Suitelet - Update view in sublist based on what is on the search form?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to display the data in the sublist based on the field input of the search form.

Answer (score 1):

Create a client script create function for fieldChanged event and write operations for and don't deploy this script on any record, you have to use this client script in for using following code.

Use this

`form.setScript('CLIENT_SCRIPT_ID);`

Comment: Okay so I have created the client script with function of field change, but data doesn't seem to be displayed on the sublist. What I'm trying to create is a custom reallocate Items page.